# Amazon Music upload - some tracks will not upload

Tags: amazon, amazon-music

I buy most of my music from Amazon increasingly MP3s and when buying CDs exploit auto-rip where possible. However that still leaves me with piles of CDs bought direct from artists and large boxed sets. So rip them to my computer and drag over to Amazon Music and upload - really easy you would think. Except, all too often one or two tracks from a CD will be rejected by Amazon. Error messages are "corrupt file" or "invalid format" despite the tracks seemingly being the same as all the others ripped at the same time. The supposedly "corrupt" files play, so surely are not corrupt; the "invalid format" files are MP3, same as those that successfully upload.

Any suggestions? It's deeply irritating to have partial albums in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue using my Amazon Music desktop app on the Mac. Ultimately my goal was to try to get my Amazon Echo devices to respond to commands for playing select songs in my library, for which I found two solutions and one of them was to pay for their cloud service. To get my iTunes library into their cloud, I figured I had to use the Amazon Music setting "Automatically import music from iTunes." I'm not sure if that's really the case, but I wonder if that's where the "corruption" really is.

At any rate, after that I did a bulk upload and let it run for a while. But many songs then got marked with an exclamation point and stated the upload failed. When I retry each one, it says it cannot upload due to corruption, which seems wrong. The file plays okay. It's an MP3. Nothing appears to be wrong with it.

So my workaround is this: In the Amazon Music app, in My Music > Songs, I right-click on the offending song and select Show on Computer. When the finder reveals the real file, I drag-and-drop the file directly into the "Upload: Drag & drop here" action on the right side of the My Music window. Then it seems to work. It's time consuming though, so maybe there is a better / faster answer.